# Summation of $\cos(2n-1)\theta$ - Extended

Tags: complex-numbers

This question is an extension to this question([Summation of cos (2n-1) theta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817109/summation-of-cos-2n-1-theta?rq=1)):

> Deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(2 n-1) \sin \left[\frac{(2 n-1) \pi}{N}\right]=-N \csc \frac{\pi}{N}$

Comment: Differentiate both sides in the link, with respect to $z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a typical method

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} {\cos((2n-1)\theta)}
& = \frac1{\sin\theta} \sum_{n=1}^{N} {\cos((2n-1)\theta)\sin\theta}\\
& = \frac1{2\sin\theta} \sum_{n=1}^{N} {(\sin(2n\theta) - \sin((2n-2)\theta))}\\
& = \frac{\sin(2N\theta)}{2\sin\theta}
\end{aligned}$$

where notice $2\cos A\sin B=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$

so your extended is

$$\begin{aligned}
-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} {\cos((2n-1)\theta)}\right)
& = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \left(\frac{\sin(2N\theta)}{2\sin\theta}\right)\\
& = -N\cos(2N\theta)\csc\theta + \frac1{2}\cot\theta\csc\theta\sin(2N\theta)
\end{aligned}$$

plug-in $\theta=\pi/N$ and you will find your answer.

Comment: Your answer is right, but in the question, it says that we must use summation of $z^(2n-1)$